# After changing all file permissions to 000, how to change it back to normal?

Tags: chmod

Sometimes, just to make sure all files are private, a command

```
sudo chmod -R 000 .
```

If we want to change back the permissions back to "normal", what command can be used?

```
sudo chmod -R 777 .
```

will not work because it makes some files that are not supposed to be executable become executable.  The executable flag is need for directories to be able to be accessible.

Comment: What do you mean by _normal_?

Comment: as what they would normally be... (without the `chmod 000`)